# Dynamically load additional Javascript source files with createElement();

Tags: javascript, callback, dynamic, onload

I have to load some script source dynamically. Since I can not use jQuery and did not know about the `XmlHttpRequest`+`eval` method, I tried to do it this way:

```
API.prototype.initCallback = null;
API.prototype.sourceLoadCnt = 0;

API.prototype.sourceReady = function () {
    this.sourceLoadCnt--;
    if(this.sourceLoadCnt===0){
        this.initCallback();    //if all sources loaded
    }
}

API.prototype.init = function (callback) {

    this.initCallback = callback;

    var _this = this;
    var js = "../../js/";

    var script1 = document.createElement('script');
    script1.type = 'text/javascript';
    script1.src = js+'script1.js';
    this.sourceLoadCnt++;
    script1.onload = function(){ _this.sourceReady() };

    var script2 = document.createElement('script');
    script2.type = 'text/javascript';
    script2.src = js+'script2.js';
    this.sourceLoadCnt++;
    script2.onload = function(){ _this.sourceReady() };

    var css1 = document.createElement('link');
    css1.type = 'text/css';
    css1.rel = 'stylesheet';
    css1.href = 'style.css';
    css1.media = 'screen';
    this.sourceLoadCnt++;
    css1.onload = function(){ _this.sourceReady() };

    head.appendChild(script1);
    head.appendChild(script2);
    head.appendChild(css1);
};
```

My problem is, that the `sourceReady`-function is called only once.

I still could change everything to load it via `XmlHttpRequest` but I am curious why my way isn't working. Does anyone have an idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be because `API.prototype.sourceLoadCnt` should not exist, it should be an instance variable that lives on `this`.

The way you have coded it now will only work if you only have a single instance, and if you only have a single instance, going the oob/prototype way seems like a design failure.

Comment: Ok, thank you. I guess I will do it the other way described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523091/dynamically-loading-javascript-files-and-load-completion-events