# Speed up the loading of Google maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps, asynchronous

I am trying to speed up my web page and the one thing which is slowing it right down is my google map. I currently have it set up like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key_goes_here&amp;sensor=false"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox.js"></script>
```

and in my document.ready script:

```
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Is there an alternative to this, I did try the asynchronous loading but I couldn't get it to work with the infobox, any help would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: impossible to give performance suggestions without knowing what the performance problems are.

Comment: You could try using [Google Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/) and host the `infobox.js` file yourself.

Answer (score 1):

You could load the map asynchronously: see https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-simple-async

If a static map will do you can use this. Once the users needs the full map you can load it then.

If you don´t need the Infobox.js remove that. In case you still need it load the packed version which is smaller (infobox_packed.js).

Last but not least messure  how you webpage is loaded in a appropriation profiler like google chromes.

Comment: Thanks, that loads in my map async :) however I am having problems with the infobox, it would seem that just including the link to it doesn't seem to work. It keeps throwing errors saying google isn't defined :-/

Comment: google is not defined because the infobox is loaded prior the main maps java file. Have a look at the callback parameter in the google maps api sample. You have to load the infobox script from this callback method. Do you use jquery? If yes see http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/ if not see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523091/dynamically-loading-javascript-files-and-load-completion-events

Answer (score 0):

You can speed things up if you include the script tags at the bottom of your document or use a javascript loading library like **[HeadJS](http://headjs.com/)**.

Comment: Yes I have my script tags at the bottom of the document already.

Answer (score 0):

You can load Google API asynchronous and after that, you can have a custom event that indicate when loading process for map has finished. You can use a photo with the map and when the event is fired, hide the photo and you will have the map without "slow load effect".