# Change the src of a script tag without id, name, or class

Tags: javascript, html

This script is loaded onto my website automatically by the host:

```
<!-- [redacted] Analytics Code -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://[redacted]/count.php"></script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

It doesn't have any identifying tags like id, name, or class, so my question is "How would I change the src of it without these things with javascript?".
I want to make the src empty because it's slowing down my website. This would be the goal:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src=""></script>
```

Or even deleting the entire script tag would be acceptable.

Comment: That won't help.  By the time your JS runs, the browser will have already downloaded and executed that script.

Comment: Why can't you remove it in the source?  I.e., so that it is never emitted in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

```
document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0].src = "location";
```

beacause `document.getElementsByTagName("script")` returns an array of all script tags you can choose which one by its index number using the brackets

Comment: This postulates that the `script` element is the first `script` element on the page. We don’t know whether it is and whether the page structure may change. Most importantly, this will not prevent the script from loading, as @Slaks commented.

Answer (score 0):

To remove it:

```
var myScript = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[0]; // or whatever index
myScript.parentNode.removeChild(myScript); // bye bye
```

But SLaks is probably right by [saying](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18326219/change-the-src-of-a-script-tag-without-id-name-or-class#comment26897004_18326219):

> That won't help. By the time your JS runs, the browser will have already downloaded and executed that script.

Comment: I think we should check the src before removing it. Otherwise, we will remove the wrong one if the side doesn't add this ".php" script any more.

Comment: Could be. OP hasn't described the problem in detail.

Comment: Sorry for not being detailed enough, this is my first post. What more did you need to know?

Answer (score 0):

As sLaks mentioned that does not help it does not help even if you change the src attribute of script tag. Instead what I suggest is in your first script file to store the entire code just make sure that you have module pattern like below

```
var yourModule = (function(){
    function yourModule(){
       ...
    }
    //your helper functions here
    function somehelper(){
        ....
    }
    yourModule.prototype.someFun1 = function(){ .. };
    yourModule.prototype.someFun2 = function(){ .. };
    return yourModule;
}());
```

Just for an example I took this pattern. The advantage is if you want to disable the entire script as just changing script does not work make

```
var xyz= new yourModule();
// start using xyz
// When you do not want yourModule anymore  
yourModule = function(){ return false; } or null;
```

will clear that function.

Then load your script again using below code

```
 var handleRequest = function( ) { //!! set up the handleRequest callback

 if(this.status != undefined) {

     /* do something with the status code here */

 }

 if(this.readyState == 4) {

      var script = document.createElement("script") ;
          script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript") ;
      var text = document.createTextNode(this.responseText) ;
          script.appendChild(text) ;

      var head = document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0] ;
          head.insertBefore(script,head.firstChild) ;

 }

 } ;

 var request ; //!! supposing you have a way to get a working XHR Object

 //.. set the XHR Object

 request.open("GET",url,true) ;
 request.overrideMimeType("text/javascript") ;
 request.onreadystatechange = handleRequest ;
 request.send(null) ;
```

Script loading is answered many times in different questions by different gurus, here is solution what I like if you want to load it through AJAX (from : [dynamically creating script: readyState never "complete"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6946631/dynamically-creating-script-readystate-never-complete))