# Load JS scripts asynchronously in order (waiting the previous one is complete)

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use [GoogleMaps.InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/) on my project, but before load this script, the GoogleMaps API has to be loaded.

Right now I have this code to load everything:

```
/**
 * Load scripts asynchronously
 */
function loadScript() {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=-MY-KEY-&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    var scriptInfoBox = document.createElement("script");
    scriptInfoBox.type = "text/javascript";
    scriptInfoBox.src = "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js";
    document.body.appendChild(scriptInfoBox);
}
```

But not always the GoogleMaps API is loaded before than GoogleMaps.InfoBox one.

**How can I load JS sorted, waiting for complete the previous one?**

Comment: Have you tried to add `onload` or `addEventListener('load',...)` and load the second script there?

Comment: I think that is the key: script.onload  = loadGoogleMapInfoBox; // function to load. I am going to try

Comment: Script `onload` is not reliable.  It doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Different browsers behave differently. See [this example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929742/can-script-readystate-be-trusted-to-detect-the-end-of-dynamic-script-loading)

Comment: using the code of the example works, but throw an exception: Uncaught ReferenceError: done is not defined. Is it normal by crossbrowser compatibility?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `load` event of the scripts:

```
function loadScript(callback) {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.type = "text/javascript";
    script.src = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=-MY-KEY-&sensor=true&callback=initialize";
    document.body.appendChild(script);
    script.onload = function() {
        var scriptInfoBox = document.createElement("script");
        scriptInfoBox.type = "text/javascript";
        scriptInfoBox.src = "http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js";
        document.body.appendChild(scriptInfoBox);
        scriptInfoBox.onload = callback;
    };
}
```

However, you will need to adapt the code a bit to make it [crossbrowser-safe like this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1929742/1048572).

Comment: Thanks, I've mentioned it in the answer

Answer (score 0):

Just use regular script tags right before `</body>`.

```
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=-MY-KEY-&sensor=true&callback=initialize"></script>
<script src="http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js"></script>
```

By default, browsers will execute scripts in the order they appear.

Comment: No, but if the script tags are immediately before the closing `</body>` tag, it doesn't really matter.  Because they are after the rest of your content, they won't block the page from displaying.

Comment: yes it does because the interpreter is blocked during the download

Comment: @jtlebi: It doesn't matter because the HTML parser (which is what is blocked during the download of a `<script>`) only has `</body></html>` left to parse.  The rest of your document will already be on-screen when the parser hits a `<script>` at the very end of the body.  The JS runtime isn't blocked either; scripts above still run and events fire.  See [this example](http://jsfiddle.net/josh3736/n8fkQ/).  The only thing that gets held up is the document's `DOMReady` event.  So instead of wiring everything up in `ready`, attach event handlers in a script directly above the include script(s).