# Loading Google Maps asynchronously with infobox error

Tags: google-maps

I have been trying to fix this since yesterday but I can't get my head around it. I am loading my google map asynchronously but The following code brings up an error which is due to the infobox not being loaded correctly.

My error is:
InfoBox is not defined

My code is:

```
function loadScript(callback) {
   var map = document.createElement('script');
   map.type = 'text/javascript';
   map.src = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=my_key_goes_here&sensor=false&callback=initialize';
   document.body.appendChild(map);            
   map.onload = function() {
      var box = document.createElement('script');
      box.type = 'text/javascript';
      box.src = 'https://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/src/infobox_packed.js';
      document.body.appendChild(box);
      box.onload = callback;
   };
}           
window.onload = loadScript;
```

Answer (score 0):

You specify an argument to your loadScript, 'callback'.  Then in your map.src you specify `callback=initialize`.  You call loadScript on window.onload, but you don't specify an argument to it.    So box.onload doesn't know any value for `callback` I'm guessing, as it can't magically guess 'initialize' from the map.src string.

Make sense?

Comment: Yes, I completely understand. I got my answer off here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12148279/load-js-scripts-asynchronously-in-order-waiting-the-previous-one-is-complete but I see the problem but I can't fix it :(

Comment: In fact do you want the initialize function to be executed on map load or box load?

Comment: It will need to be execute on box load for it to work, I think