# jsonp & jquery does jQuery make a script node in DOM?

Tags: jquery, jsonp

Does jQuery create a `script` node in the DOM setting the source equal to the request and then remove the `script` node?

I was debugging it in firebug and I never noticed an any extra `script` nodes ever being added.  Wondering how jQuery handles this?

E.g.

```
$(document).ready(
    function(){
        $.ajax({
          url: "...",
          type: 'GET',
          dataType: 'jsonp'
        });
    }
);
```

Comment: Your document ready needs an anonymous function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the source of the `jQuery.ajaxTransport` function in the jQuery source. it returns an object with a `send` element containing a function that adds the script to the DOM. This script element has an `onload` and `onreadystate` change handler that removes itself from the DOM.

Comment: Yea, I see on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929742/can-script-readystate-be-trusted-to-detect-the-end-of-dynamic-script-loading) both of those have to be set due to browser inconsistencies.

Comment: Also, I'm guessing I didn't see the `script` nodes being added to the DOM because it was happening very, very quickly that they were being added and then removed.  I do see that the script was loaded, though.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, jQuery creates a `script` element in the DOM. (This is the only way that JSON-P can work.)

Comment: Is it removed, though?  e.g. if I make many such JSONP calls will the DOM be flooded with all those script nodes?

Comment: @user17753: I'd be shocked if it left them lying around. jQuery's source is convoluted and hard to read in this area, but it should be trivial to find out: Do three or four JSON-P calls and then look at the DOM in Chrome Tools or Firebug or whatever you use.

Comment: Yea, as I originally said in the question, I never noticed any being added/removed.

Comment: @user17753: They're definitely added (again, otherwise JSON-P just wouldn't work), but if they're removed (and I'm sure they are), it would naturally happen fairly quickly (e.g., as soon as the JSON-P script loaded).

Comment: Ok so, I'd assume that somehow it passes the callback function to another function that executes the callback, and then executes another function (right after) to remove the `script` node from the DOM.

Comment: @user17753: Or it might remove the node first (since that would have no effect on the code loaded by the node), but yeah, that's almost certainly what it's doing.