# Loading asynchronous JS file & readyState?

Tags: javascript

I was reading the book :  *Third party Javascript* :

There was a sample code : (load external js)

```
  (function ()
    {
        var script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.src = 'js_file.js';
        script.onload = script.onreadystatechange = function ()
        {
            var rdyState = script.readyState;
            if (!rdyState || /loaded|complete/.test(rdyState))
            {
                /*...*/
                script.onload = null;
                script.onreadystatechange = null;
            }
        };
        var entry = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
        entry.parentNode.insertBefore(script, entry);
    })();
```

I'm trying to understand that line :

`if (!rdyState || /loaded|complete/.test(rdyState))...`

I'm getting `undefined` in `script.readyState`

[image]

**Questions** :

- Why am I getting `undefined` in `script.readyState` ?
- Should readystate return numbers or strings ?  accoring to the regex test it suppose to return strings. but Ive seen many places where it returns numbers. so... ?

**http://jsbin.com/ipOrIDeY/4/edit**

*(chrome 31. thanks Google but no thanks for the font smoothing version.(32))*

Comment: Seems the same problem [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1929742/can-script-readystate-be-trusted-to-detect-the-end-of-dynamic-script-loading)

Comment: @guy777 The answer there talks about onreadystate never gets called . but onload does..... **which makes me ask** : does readyState is  set only when the onreadstate is called ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my code to load javascript files，it works very well,readystate returns string,but it's value depends on your javascript engine.

```
 var n = document.createElement('script');
          n.setAttribute('type', 'text/javascript');
          n.setAttribute('src', 'Your src');
          n.setAttribute('async', true);
          n.onerror = function() {
            callback()
            n.onerror = null;
          };

          n.onload = n.onreadystatechange = function() {
            if (!this.readyState || this.readyState === 'loaded' || this.readyState === 'complete') {
              callback()
              n.onload = n.onreadystatechange = null;
            }
          };

          document.body.appendChild(n);
```

Comment: I think readyState not working on Chrome or Firefox. [Here's a solution](http://web.onassar.com/blog/2011/04/07/readystate-firing-for-dynamically-loaded-scripts/)